# Search and replace in VSCode

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio-code

I am trying to search and replace in VSCode in all the xml files. I am interested in the below line in all the files which has name "somekey"

```
<setting name="somekey" value="abc-def.google.xyz.com" />
<setting name="somekey" value="abc-xyz.google.xyz.com" />
```

I am trying to convert this line to

```
<setting name="somekey" value="abc-def-ghi.google.xyz.com" />
<setting name="somekey" value="abc-xyz-ghi.google.xyz.com" />
```

so far I have this

(<setting name="somekey" value="abc-)((.|n)*?.google.xyz.com). How do I make it so the group 1 includes everything until the first ".". Any pointers?
https://regex101.com/r/WeEkgQ/1

Comment: You could find `(<setting name="somekey" value="abc-.*?)(\.google\.xyz\.com")` and replace with `$1.ghi$2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the part matching until `.google.xyz.com` to the first group, and in the replacement use the 2 capture groups `$1.ghi$2`

To match the dot literally you have to escape it `\.` and note that the current pattern is not matching the closing  `/>`

```
(<setting name="somekey" value="abc-.*?)(\.google\.xyz\.com")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7m9hs/1)

**Note** that this part `(.|n)` matches either any char or a `n` char. If you meant to use `(.|\n)` you could use `[\s\S\r]+?` instead of using the alternation to match over multiple lines making it a bit more efficient.